# How to restart a Kinect

Tags: c#, xna, kinect

So I'm writing an XNA app using the Kinect SDK and when my game changes from the game screen to another screen, I stop the Kinect by using

```
sensor.Stop();
sensor.Dispose();
```

And while it does work it has considerable lag and makes my game look unresponsive for at least 10 seconds. Then after that screen I go back to a game screen again but with different settings. So I use

```
//set all my event handlers
sensor.blahStream += myFunction;
sensor.Start();
```

Is this the best way to restart a Kinect?

Comment: May I ask why you are restarting the Kinect?  What is the rationale behind turning it on/off?

Comment: To remove all settings I had placed on the Kinect (skeletal smoothing, event handlers, etc) so that I can use it again "from scratch" so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fiddled around some more, putting the stopping on a separate thread seems to work.

```
stopGameThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(stopGame));
stopGameThread.Start();
```

that calls this method:

```
void stopGame(object sender)
{
    gScreen.sensor.Stop();
    gScreen.sensor.Dispose();
    running = false;
}
```

`gScreen` is the game screen contained in this game screen wrapper.

If anyone has any better answers feel free to post them.